# Slow Python regex without catastrophic backtracking

Tags: python, regex

I have 2 csv files. The first, `input`, consists of input street addresses with various errors. The second, `ref` is a clean street address table. Records within `input` need to be matched to records within `ref`. Converting the files to lists with unique records is fast, but once I get to the matching process, it's dreadfully slow, taking a full 85 seconds just to match two addresses within `input` to `ref` without any regular expressions! I realize that the size of `ref` is the issue here; it is over 1 million records in length and the file size is 30 MB. I was anticipating some performance issues with these kinds of sizes, but taking this long for only two records is unacceptable (realistically, I may have to match up to 10,000 records or more. Additionally, I will eventually need to embed some regex to `ref` items to allow for more flexible matching. Testing the new regex module is even worse, taking a whopping 185 seconds for the same two `input` records. Does anybody know the best way to speed things up substantially? Can I somehow index by zip code, for example?

Here are sample addresses from input and ref, respectively (after preprocessing):

```
60651 N SPRINGFIELD AVE CHICAGO
60061 BROWNING CT VERNON HILLS
```

Here is what I have so far. (being a novice, I realize that there is probably all kinds of inefficiencies with my code, but that's not the issue) :

```
import csv, re

f = csv.reader(open('/Users/benjaminbauman/Documents/inputsample.csv','rU'))

columns = zip(*f)

l = list(columns)

inputaddr = l[0][1:]

f = csv.reader(open('/Users/benjaminbauman/Documents/navstreets.csv','rU'))
f.next()

reffull = []
for row in f:
    row = str(row[0:7]).strip(r'['']').replace("\'","")
    if not ", , , , ," in row: reffull.append(row) 

input = list(set(inputaddr))

ref1 = list(set(reffull))
ref2 = ref1

input_scrub = []
for i in inputaddr:
    t = i.replace(',',' ')
    input_scrub.append(' '.join(t.split()))

ref_scrub = []

for i in ref1:
    t = i.replace(',',' ')
    ref_scrub.append(' '.join(t.split()))

output_iter1 = dict([ (i, [ r for r in ref_scrub if re.match(r, i) ]) for i in input_scrub ])

unmatched_iter1 = [i for i, j in output_iter1.items() if len(j) < 1]
matched_iter1 = {i: str(j[0][1]).strip(r'['']') for i, j in output_iter1.items() if len(j) is 1}
tied_iter1 = {k: zip(*(v))[1] for k,v in output_iter1.iteritems() if len(v) > 1}
```

Comment: If you have a table with ~1 million records, why don't you use a sql database?

Comment: Working with Python, there seems to be the most documentation on Sqlite. Is this what you would recommend?

Comment: Yes, check out the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: Will do. Hopefully working with sqlite will not make this project too much harder. Pressing deadline..

Comment: I see other people with similar issues have chosen mmap. Would this possibly work? I'm looking for a solution that would ideally not require learning SQL.

Comment: Back to your original question though, can you identify which line is taking the most time? Is it the one that starts `output_iter1 = dict(...`? Also, rather than focusing on regexes, which are 'relatively' slow, have you considered sanitizing your input prior to checking for matches?

Comment: Yes, it is the line that you've identified. Using your suggestion, I tried replacing the `re.match(r, i)` attempt with `r == i` and the difference is outstanding, with the latter being almost immediate compared to nearly over a minute for the former. Strangely, using multiple re.sub runs on `ref` is not very time consuming at all. However, I ultimately want to use "fuzzy matching" using Python's new Regex library to allow for occasional unidentifiable errors within a predefined edit distance. So unfortunately, using `r == i` for the project would not work.

Comment: Apologies for the follow-up comment, but I tried running `output_iter1 = [r for r in ref_scrub if re.match('60651 N SPRINGFIELD AVE CHICAGO', r)]` in replace of the original `output_iter1` line, and the search result was almost immediate. Any explanation on the seemingly inconsistent behavior?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24217/discussion-between-joel-cornett-and-user1185790)

Comment: @user1185790 Hello. I don't perceive your precise goal. You must compare addresses in **input** file and **ref** file for what ? Do you want to correct the items in **input** with verified patterns in **ref** ? Do you want to record the items of **input** in **ref** after having diagnosed and corrected them ? What are two addresses matching and two addresses not matching ?

Comment: @eyquem My intentions are ultimately to match roughly 10,000 `input` addresses (containing errors) to the large table, `ref`. This will require multiple passes with increasing flexibility, eventually using "fuzzy" regular expressions contained within the regex module - pypi.python.org/pypi/regex. The output would be a csv file with a field of all the `input` addresses, and an adjacent field with corresponding address matches found within the `ref` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fuzzy regex in the new module, maybe you could use the difflib module, if the execution time is acceptable:

```
import difflib


REF = ['455 Gateway Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239',
       '10 Devoe St, Brooklyn, NY 11211',
       '8801 Queens Blvd, Elmhurst, NY 11373 ',
       '342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 ',
       '4488 E Live Oak Ave, Arcadia, CA 91006',
       '1134 N Vermont Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90029',
       '1101 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20036 ',
       '3001 Syringa St, Hopeful-City, AL 48798',
       '950 Laurel St, Minneapolis, KS 67467']


INPUT = ['4554 Gagate Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239',
         '10 Devoe St, Brooklyn, NY 11211',
         '8801 Queens Blvd, Elmhurst, NY 11373 ',
         '342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 ',
         '4488 E Live Oak Ave, Arcadia, CA 91006',
         '1134 N Vermont Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90029',
         '1101 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20036 ',
         '3001 Syrinuy St, Hopeful Dam, AL 48798',
         '950 Laurel St, Minneapolis, KS 67467',
         '455 Gateway Doctor, Forgotten Place, NY 11239',
         '10 Devoe St, Brook., NY 11211',
         '82477 Queens Blvd, Elmerst, NY 11373 ',
         '342 Waithe Street, Brooklyn, MN 11249 ',
         '4488 E Live Poke Ave, Arcadia, CA 145',
         '1134 N Vermiculite Ave, Liz Angelicas, CA 90029',
         '1101 1st St NW, Washing, DC 20036 ']


def treatment(inp,reference,crit,gcm = difflib.get_close_matches):
    for input_item in inp:
        yield (input_item,gcm(input_item,reference,1000,crit))


for a,b in treatment(INPUT,REF,0.65):
    print '\n- %s\n     %s' % (a, '\n     '.join(b))
```

the result is:

```
- 4554 Gagate Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239
     455 Gateway Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239
     342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 

- 10 Devoe St, Brooklyn, NY 11211
     10 Devoe St, Brooklyn, NY 11211

- 8801 Queens Blvd, Elmhurst, NY 11373 
     8801 Queens Blvd, Elmhurst, NY 11373 

- 342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 
     342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 
     455 Gateway Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239

- 4488 E Live Oak Ave, Arcadia, CA 91006
     4488 E Live Oak Ave, Arcadia, CA 91006

- 1134 N Vermont Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90029
     1134 N Vermont Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90029

- 1101 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20036 
     1101 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20036 

- 3001 Syrinuy St, Hopeful Dam, AL 48798
     3001 Syringa St, Hopeful-City, AL 48798

- 950 Laurel St, Minneapolis, KS 67467
     950 Laurel St, Minneapolis, KS 67467

- 455 Gateway Doctor, Forgotten Place, NY 11239
     455 Gateway Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239

- 10 Devoe St, Brook., NY 11211
     10 Devoe St, Brooklyn, NY 11211

- 82477 Queens Blvd, Elmerst, NY 11373 
     8801 Queens Blvd, Elmhurst, NY 11373 

- 342 Waithe Street, Brooklyn, MN 11249 
     342 Wythe Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249 
     455 Gateway Dr, Brooklyn, NY 11239

- 4488 E Live Poke Ave, Arcadia, CA 145
     4488 E Live Oak Ave, Arcadia, CA 91006

- 1134 N Vermiculite Ave, Liz Angelicas, CA 90029
     1134 N Vermont Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90029

- 1101 1st St NW, Washing, DC 20036 
     1101 17th St NW, Washington, DC 20036
```

Comment: Useful alternative, eyquem. I considred the difflib module earlier, but wanted to incorporate regular expressions into the matching process as well. The code you gave is faster (but still a bit slower than preferred), matching about one record within `input` to `ref` per second. Given your suggestion, I could preprocess both lists using `re.sub` to allow for increasingly higher tolerance per pass.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me why the line

```
output_iter1 = dict([ (i, [ r for r in ref_scrub if re.match(r, i) ]) for i in input_scrub ])
```

was taking so long. The matching process is searching for a match for every item within the exceptionally large list, `ref` to items within the smaller list, `input`, as opposed to the other way around. Unfortunately, I wanted it structured this way so that I could embed regular expressions to items within `ref`, as these items are tokenized by address attribute to allow for easy anchoring. I suppose there are two workarounds given my limited understanding of sql. The first could use the idea brought up in my last comment per eyquem's suggestion. The second could use a lookup (index?) by city and zip code attributes using an equals to statement before doing more complicated matching, either with regex or difflib.

I've split items within `input` and `ref` so that the city and zip code attributes are separate items within a list, such as the following:

```
ref ('COVE POINTE CT', 'BLOOMINGTON, 61704')
input ('S EBERHART', 'CHICAGO, 60628')
```

The following allows me to narrow the search to the portion of `ref` that shares the same city and zip code. This narrows the length of time down to 56 seconds for an `input` file containing over 1000 records. This is substantially better.

```
matchaddr = []
refaddr = []
unmatched = []
for i in ref:
    for t in input:
        if t[1] == i[1]:
            if re.match(i[0],t[0]):
                matchaddr.append(t[0] + ', ' + t[1])
                refaddr.append(i[0] + ', ' + i[1])
```

Now I can use my beloved regex again (pending that the expressions don't cause additional problems, such as catastrophic backtracking). Also, this code's speed is because perfect matches are found first with city and zip code attributes. If I try to allow for flexible matching with city and zip code as well, speed will likely be greatly sacrificed. Unfortunately, it may have to come to that point (input contains messy city and zip code attributes as well).